# Why am I getting memory quota exceeded errors on Heroku even while unused? (play2/scala)

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.0

Just sitting with no requests, I get memory keeps on increasing, eventually to memory quota exceeded.  There are multiple things I don't understand.

1. Why memory use keeps increasing when no requests?
2. Where does the value of "Process running mem" come from (does not seem to be a sum of any combination of numbers from the Heap and Non-Heap usage that I can tell).
3. Why does it exceed even though I have the recommended `JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -javaagent:heroku-javaagent-1.2.jar=stdout=true`?

Here is a sample of the log file

```
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage     (Heap): used: 275M committed: 349M max:349M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage (Non-Heap): used: 37M committed: 37M max:219M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Threads                : total: 37 daemon: 7 non-daemon: 21 internal: 9 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage     (Heap): used: 276M committed: 349M max:349M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage (Non-Heap): used: 37M committed: 37M max:219M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Threads                : total: 37 daemon: 7 non-daemon: 21 internal: 9 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage     (Heap): used: 277M committed: 349M max:349M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage (Non-Heap): used: 37M committed: 37M max:219M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Threads                : total: 37 daemon: 7 non-daemon: 21 internal: 9 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage     (Heap): used: 277M committed: 349M max:349M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage (Non-Heap): used: 37M committed: 37M max:219M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Threads                : total: 37 daemon: 7 non-daemon: 21 internal: 9 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage     (Heap): used: 278M committed: 349M max:349M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage (Non-Heap): used: 37M committed: 37M max:219M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Threads                : total: 37 daemon: 7 non-daemon: 21 internal: 9 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage     (Heap): used: 212M committed: 349M max:349M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage (Non-Heap): used: 37M committed: 37M max:219M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Threads                : total: 37 daemon: 7 non-daemon: 21 internal: 9 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage     (Heap): used: 213M committed: 349M max:349M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage (Non-Heap): used: 37M committed: 37M max:219M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Threads                : total: 37 daemon: 7 non-daemon: 21 internal: 9 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage     (Heap): used: 213M committed: 349M max:349M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage (Non-Heap): used: 37M committed: 37M max:219M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Threads                : total: 37 daemon: 7 non-daemon: 21 internal: 9 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage     (Heap): used: 214M committed: 349M max:349M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Memory Usage (Non-Heap): used: 37M committed: 37M max:219M 
app/web.1:  heroku-javaagent: JVM Threads                : total: 37 daemon: 7 non-daemon: 21 internal: 9 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
heroku/web.1:  Process running mem=517M(101.1%) 
heroku/web.1:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

Answer (score 5):

This issue should not be specific to Heroku and should (ideally) be able to be reproduced locally. First, I would recommend running your app locally the same way Heroku runs it:

- Run [`sbt clean compile stage`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/blob/master/bin/compile#L77) to create the `target/start` launcher
- Launch your app with [`target/start -Dhttp.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/blob/master/bin/release#L23) (set PORT to whatever you want)

Then I would use a memory profiler, such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), to attach to your app running locally to see what's going on.

If this does not work or you'd like to get a better breakdown of the memory usage on Heroku, I'd recommend enabling [log-runtime-metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics). This can also be used with [Log2Viz](https://log2viz.herokuapp.com/) to get a realtime memory visualizations.

Answer (score 2):

Just had a similar problem. I wasn't able to reproduce the problem locally. 
It turned out that we had a file appender in our logging configuration. Writing to the logs made the memory grow. 
You can verify that, by writing a small app that logs a lot. If you enable log-runtime-metrics, you'll see memory_cache and memory_total grow.

Comment: Can you share more details on your logging configuration? Is there anything Heroku could do to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Enable log-runtime-metrics in heroku:

```
$ heroku labs:enable log-runtime-metrics
Enabling log-runtime-metrics for myapp... done
$ heroku restart
```

This will allow you do view memory usage in the logs

```
heroku logs -t
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics

Comment: -1 this was already mentioned in the other answer from six months ago and adds no additional value.

Comment: Fair enough i missed the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same error message in grails application, i read this [article](http://www.objectpartners.com/2014/05/13/grails-r14-error-memory-quota-exceeded-on-heroku/) the solution was simple create a **system.property** file in root folder with this **java.runtime.version=1.7** as content, then i redeploy the application and error R14 its gone

i hope it is helpful